# C# Dynamic Form Help

Tags: c#, forms, dynamic, onclick

I'm trying to make something of a Tile-Map editor in C# using picture-boxes (the simplest way i could think to throw tiles into a form)

The code that Generates the picture boxes is:

```
public void Generate_Tiles(int width, int height)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();
                    picturebox.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
                    picturebox.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
                    picturebox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((x*32) + 4, (y*32) + 4);
                    picturebox.Name = x+y+"tile";
                    picturebox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
                    picturebox.TabIndex = 0;
                    picturebox.TabStop = false;
                    picturebox.Click += new System.EventHandler(TileBox_Clicked));
                    map.Controls.Add(picturebox);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
```

That part works, as long as i use a small number of picture boxes at a time (8 by 8 seems to be the maximum that it wants to display in a decent amount of time)

I want to perform some action when the user clicks on a specified picture-box, which is why i have a onclick method, that's where i run into problems, all the picture-boxes are called... picture-box. As far as i can tell, there's no way for me to tell which picture-box the user clicked.

I will probably need to remake the way the dynamic form works anyway, since i cant get very many picture boxes, but I think the main problem will still be there, as long as i want it to be dynamic (which i do), not all of the tile-maps will be the same size.

Ive never done anything like this, and I've looked for ways to override the onclick event... which i couldn't find, and i couldn't find a good tile-engine that's up to date to use (except for XNA, but that's a little over the top for a simple tile-editor, i think)

Im likely going in the opposite direction then what i need to be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sender in your event handler will be the `PictureBox` which was clicked.

```
    void TileBox_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
        if(pictureBox != null)
        {
            //do stuff with your pictureBox
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...and for the sake of completeness, you'd probably want to make sure your casting works by checking for mull after that step - you may accidentally wire up another object's Click event to that method (although it might just be me that does things like that ;) )...

Comment: @ZombieSheep Yep; checking for null would be expected...edited for "completeness" ;)

Comment: >_> I guess i forgot that the Name of the object being PictureBox doesnt matter if the object that is the sender refers specifically to the object i need, what i THOUGHT, was that trying to change 1 picturebox via sender would change them all, but now that i think about it, they all have unique pointers...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just cast the sender object to a PictureBox in your event handler, and work with that?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in your event handler is the clicked control (which will be the PictureBox.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken this approach with a map tile editor as well. As others have said, you can use the sender parameter and cast it to a PictureBox to get the PictureBox object that was clicked. But I think you'll find (you probably already have) that a decent map size will really slow things down.

You might reconsider XNA. It seems complicated, and it's not as easy to get something working as just generating a bunch of PictureBox objects. But it's fast, and it's you can get a 2D map being displayed fairly quickly. You can also extend it easier, for example if you want your map to have different editable layers (terrain, etc.).

Comment: We actually went with compiling each tile into one large image, the 256/256 loads quickly enough, and the fact that it redraws with each tile edit doesnt hinder the editing process too much, we plan on making it 3d instead of topdown via XNA, but for now we want the basic system for our game devs to use, then we will worry about making it look nice for end-users :D

Answer (score 0):

There are actually lots of ways to do this. I think the easiest is to use the `sender` of your event handler, which will point you back to the clicked button:

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var box = sender as PictureBox;
     if (box != null)
     {
         //...
```

You can also create and add event handlers dynamically, which is an interesting option:

```
        //...
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();

                pictureBox.Click += new Action<object, EventArgs>(
                     (sender, e) => { doStuff(pictureBox); }
                );
```

In the above code, `doStuff` gets `pictureBox` as a parameter, so it knows which object it's supposed to work on.